# What is the farthest point in the Star Wars galaxy right before the Intergalactic Void?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I remember years ago on Wookieepedia, I read an short article about an astronomical body that was the furthest point in the galaxy until you got into the Intergalactic Void of space between galaxies. I’m tempted to say it was a nebula but I’m not sure. I think it was mentioned in the SWTOR game, the still ongoing MMORPG one. I know that the Yuuzhan Vong breached the galaxy at Belkadan, which implies it’s the furthest planet and in Disney canon, Batuu is the last stop before Wild Space but Belkadan may just be a vector point (hence the novel Vector Prime) and Wild Space is huge after Batuu. So does anybody know the furthest point or am I just imagining I read this on Wookieepedia.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect what you're referring to is the blurb for [Galaxy's Edge: Black Spire](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy%27s_Edge:_Black_Spire) which refers to Batuu as being the furthest point.... before Wild Space

> A planet of lush forests, precarious mountains, and towering, petrified trees, **Batuu is on the furthest possible frontier of the galactic map, the last settled world before the mysterious expanse of Wild Space.**

---

As far as the *farthest known object/s* are concered, these have changed over the years;

- On the first official map (from 1998's [Behind the Magic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Behind_the_Magic)), it was Mon Calamari.

  [image]
- The galaxy map from the (2002) [Official Star Wars Fact Files](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File) offers a few additional contenders including Kamino and Belkadan.

  [image]
- The map from the (2009) [Star Wars: The Essential Atlas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas) has **Belkadan** slightly higher up, and clearly now right on the northern edge of the galaxy. It also mentions the Red Nebula as being the farthest object at galactic south.

  [image]
- The fully canon map from the (2016) [*Star Wars: Galactic Atlas*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Galactic_Atlas) factbook has **Mortis** as the farthest object.

  [image]